# How to show a media element in full screen on screen rotation?

Tags: windows, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1

In my Windows Phone 8.1 RT app, I have a media element inside a Pivot control. On screen rotation, I want to make the media element play in full screen.

I'm referring the Jerry Nixon's Orientation Behavior (http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/12/the-two-ways-to-handle-orientation-in.html) for handling orientations on other pages.

But I can't seem to make the media element full screen on rotation because visual states don't allow me to change parent-child relationship on a page.

My question is how to take that media element outside of the pivot control and make it full screen. Here's an outline of the XAML:

```
<Grid>
<Pivot>
<PivotItem>
<MediaElement x:Name="To Be Made Full Screen"/>
</PivotItem>
<PivotItem>
<TextBlock/>
</PivotItem>
</Pivot>
</Grid>
```

Comment: can you share your xaml

Comment: yes. posted an outline.